# Spring autowiring with parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to do autowiring using dynamic parameter, I know we can declare a class with @component and make the class available for autowiring, but what if I have a class with parametrized construtor. I can we use autowiring and intialise the object with paramter?
Please see the below snippet.

```
@Component
public class A{
   public A(Object B){
     // do something
   }
}


public class C{
  @Autowire
  private A a;

  public foo(){
      B b = getBfromSomewhere();
     // create object of A using parameter B
     // like a = new A(b);
      }

  }
```

Comment: to use autowire , the class in which the autowire annotation is used should also be bean.

Comment: see this tutorial for more understanding https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after going through the configuration annotation. One should first must tell spring, how it should create the bean for example.

```
@Configuration
public class Appconfig{

 @Bean(name="a")
 public A getA(B b){
   return A(b); 
 }
}
```

Later when you are using it.

```
public class C{
  @Autowire
  private BeanFactory factory;

   public foo(){
     B b = getBfromSomewhere();
     A a    = factory.getBean(A.class,b)

   }

}
```